# Replace part of string with something else

Tags: c#, string, replace

I would like to replace the values in a string formatted as [@ID=###] with something else. The string can have [@ID=###] and other things but it's the bit within the brackets that I am concerned with. For example:

[@ID=3671818]+2

For that, I want to replace only "[@ID=3671818]"--the "+2" needs to stay as it is.

I would like to try something like this:

```
value = value.Replace().Insert();
```

But I know that won't work. Is there a way to do this in one line of code or do I need to work with various string variables? As in, do I need a startIndex variable and endIndex variable to remove the "[@ID=" and "]" pieces first so I can target just what is in between?

Comment: Sounds like you're making a lot of work for yourself. Instead of removing and prepending characters, why not just create a new string and append "+2" to it?

Comment: @BobKaufman I'm not sure I know what you mean...? Do you mean I should use a Split() at some point?

Comment: If all you want is to create a string that ends with "+2", why don't you just do that rather than deleting characters from a string and inserting new ones?

Comment: The "+2" is just an example. It could be "*3" or "+2*1.5" or "/5" or it could just be the value in the brackets.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what Regular Expressions are for:

```
string str = @"[@ID=3671818]+2";
var newStr = Regex.Replace(str, @"\[.*\]", "TEST");
Console.WriteLine(newStr);
//newStr = "TEST+2"
```

Everything within brackets (including the brackets) will be replaced with your replacement string.

If you want to keep the brackets, you'd use

```
@"(?<=\[).*(?=\])"  //newStr = "[TEST]+2"
```

which uses lookaheads and lookbehinds to find text within brackets, and replace that text.

As far as learning Regex, there are a ton of guides out there, and I prefer [RegExr](http://www.regexr.com/) for testing them.